Platformio STM32L4 FreeRtos
i have a simple project in Platformio for STM32L4 , i want to use FreeRtos Task. however some crasy stuff is going on
here is the Platformio.ini  i am using freeRtos V1
[env:nucleo_l476rg]
platform = ststm32
board = nucleo_l476rg
framework = stm32cube
upload_protocol = custom
upload_command = openocd -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32l4x.cfg -c "init; reset halt; stm32l4x mass_erase 0; program {$SOURCE} 0x08000000 verify reset exit"
debug_tool = stlink
debug_init_break = tbreak main
;lib_deps = FreeRTOS
 libextra_dirs = Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS

build_flags =
  -IMiddlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS
  -IMiddlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F
  -IMiddlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/include

;src_filter = +<Scr/>+<Drivers/>+<Middlewares/>

; select linker file generated by CubeMX
;board_build.ldscript = STM32L476RGTx_FLASH.ld
lib_archive = no

folder
my code
#include "cmsis_os.h"
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "stm32l4xx_hal.h"

osThreadId MYTaskHandle;
osThreadId MainProcesTaskHandle;
void MYTask()
{

 //DO nothing
}
int main(void)
{
osThreadDef(MYT, MYTask, osPriorityNormal, 0, 512);
            MYTaskHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(MYT), NULL);
}

and the error
Building in release mode
Linking .pio\build\nucleo_l476rg\firmware.elf
.pio/build/nucleo_l476rg/src/main.o: In function main': main.c:(.text.startup.main+0x6a): undefined reference to osThreadCreate'
f i go into the osThreadCreate  right click to Go to definition it goes straight to cmsis_os.h just fine

I've never used PlatformIO, but on the assumption that a ; character indicates a comment, you seem to have commented out the following: ;lib_deps = FreeRTOS

yeah , however commented or not it is not working
